# Variable lengths differ error message in R

Tags: r, dataset, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression on the spam dataset from `https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/`.  The dependent variable is in the last column, which is given as V58 after I import the data in R.  But I get the error message

> variable lengths differ (found in 'V1')

I've checked for `NA`s using `na.omit`, I tried removing the `V1` column just to see if that fixes the issue, but I get the same message.  I tried using the old `cv.glm` function instead, but that does not work.  I also tried referring to the dependent variable as `spam.data$V58`.  I am stuck.  What am I missing?  Below is the code I have so far to just get the model.

```
spam.data <- data_frame(read.table(datapathname))

dim(spam.data)
str(spam.data)
summary(spam.data)

set.seed(2718)
row.number = sample(1:nrow(spam.data), 0.7*nrow(spam.data))
train = spam.data[row.number,]
test = spam.data[-row.number,]
dim(train)
dim(test)

model.logistic = glm(as.factor(spam.data[58])~., data=train, family=binomial) #The error gets thrown here.

summary(model.logistic)
```

I should also say that the way I created the data set was to copy and paste the data from the website to a text file and read it into R from that file.  The info on the site says we should get 4601 rows and 58 columns, and indeed we get this size dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes when you fit the logistic model:

- The data is train, but you take the outcome from spam.data. These two data frames have different numbers of observations. Instead, use `train[58]` as the outcome.
- When you change the outcome to a factor with as.factor, a single level NA is returned, because the as.factor does not work on the dbl format of the outcome. Therefore, first unlist the outcome with `unlist(train[58])`.

Using these two changes the model worked for me:

```
model.logistic = glm(as.factor(unlist(train[58]))~., data=train, family=binomial)
```

Comment: ... I'm so blind... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a column from `spam.data` (`spam` in the example below) as your response; that has length 4601. Your response variables are coming from the `train` data set, which only has 3221 rows.

```r
## archived on CRAN, need to install with remotes::install_version
remotes::install_version("ElemStatLearn", version = "2015.6.26.2")
library(ElemStatLearn)  ## loads 'spam' data set
set.seed(2718)
nr <- nrow(spam)
row.number <- sample(nr, round(0.7*nr))
train <- spam[row.number,]

## column 58 is called 'spam'; best practice to refer to variables
##  by name rather than index where possible
glm(as.factor(spam) ~., data=train, family=binomial)
```